# How to change the textbox placehoder color using textbox "id"

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text" id="sample" placeholder="hai"/>
```

Here how to change the color of placeholder using textbox "id"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using css

Sample CSS

```
#sample::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
  color:    red;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o713Loem/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use css to do this:

```
input#hai::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red !important;
}

input#hai:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: red !important;  
}

input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: red !important;  
}

input#hai:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color : red !important;
}
```

Comment: As taken from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/